# how to update a table and get the updated value for further use in a multi user web environment

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I am working with asp.net 2.0 and sql server 2005. I have a problem and need some help, so trying to describe it below:

**THE SITUATION**

I have a few tables to hold data for billing information. The first table has each dedicated to each location, and a serial number that can be incremented. The concept is to update this data based on location, every time there is a new bill, so may be location A has serial 25 since it is doing well but location B has serial 5.

**THE PROBLEM**
SO based on this requirement I need to update a table to get the latest serial for a particular location and then use that serial for other tables which will be holding the billing details. The second part is as regular as it can be, but generating a new number, and getting this value is my problem. Since this will be multi user system, so I want some robust solution. Can some one help please. I do not know whether I can use a identity field for this purpose or not. Please help.

Regards
arunendra

Comment: Can you give a limited schema of your billing info tables?  Specifically, how they currently relate to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Use an identity on your actual bill table.  Whenever you insert a new record, go update the table that contains the location/last used serial number.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But I want not to increase rows and want to update a row based on a location, I think now, that a trigger can solve my problem, can you throw some light in this regard.